# Switch for alternating between outlets

Tags: electrical, electric-vehicle

I'm installing a Tesla charger, but I also want to install a NEMA 14-50 outlet so other EV owners can charge in that spot as well, but as it's one spot, both won't be used at the same time. I don't want to have to run two independent lines when only one will be in use at a time. Is there something I could use that would take one line input, and output two separate lines with a toggle switch determining which one is active? And even if so, would such a thing be within code?

Comment: What size breaker and wire is required for a Tesla home charger? Do Tesla chargers come with a NEMA 14-50 plug or are they hard wired?

Comment: Are you *surrrrrree* this can't be a 30A circuit? Nudge wink.  If you can do this with a 30A circuit, different rules.

Comment: https://www.tesla.com/support/home-charging-installation/wall-connector gives 40-A 2-pole breaker for the Model 3 (std and mid range) and 60-A for Model 3 long range and all higher models.

Comment: @Harper, according to the Tesla site the charger can be set for many different current levels and so could work on a 30-A 240-V circuit charging at 24 A giving 2 mi of range per hour of charging for a Model 3.

Comment: Indeed, it can be throttled to match your needs, but at the point you might as well use the cheaper mobile charger. 60 amps is needed to make full use of the wall charger, so 4 gauge is needed. I presume 4-4-4-6 cable will suffice for that?

Comment: Is there a known effect of charging rate on the service life of the battery (presumably slower charging giving longer life of battery)? So one could use a lower charging rate for ordinary daily use, and the maximum for a special need.

Comment: When the chart says "55A @60C", *you are allowed to round up to 60*.  6 is my breakover point for switching for aluminum, so I would use 6Cu or 4Al depending on cost.  You don't get any brownie points for using copper, the fear associated with aluminum is totally inapplicable to both modern wire and large wire at these feeder sizes.

Comment: @JimStewart The car's internal charging mechanism handles this for you, and it's pretty conservative. The relationship between charging speed and battery longevity is a function of how full the battery is. An empty battery can consume 150kw no problem, those last few percentage is barely a trickle. Think like a cup under a faucet where water splashing out = battery damage. At first you can go full speed, but as the cup fills you need to dial it back. It's also very difficult to fill the cup to the very top without spilling, so general guidance is to avoid filling above 90%.

Comment: I have heard that the lifetime of a L-ion battery is inversely related to the time spent at higher states of charge. Is that true? So for ordinary use this would indicate operating around 50 % charge, e.g., for a daily commute charge to 80% and use down to 30% . . .  Which model Tesla are you planning this charger for?

Comment: Indeed, and Tesla themselves recommend 80% for people who charge up daily. I have a Model 3, which by far has their most stable batteries, the 2170s. At 80% You can expect around 5% degradation at 50k miles and 10% at 150k miles. With available data, it's projected 20% degradation at around 500k miles. Warranty will replace the battery at 30% (that is, 70% remaining). Charging to 90% will have an impact, but I find the projected losses acceptable.

Comment: Is it the process of charging *to* higher states of charge that causes degradation or is it the length of time the battery is *in* the higher states?

Comment: If I recall a news story correctly, Tesla flashed a software update to everyone in Florida right before the hurricane, telling their chargers to top the battery to 100% and allowing cars to discharge much deeper than is normally allowed under terms of sale, i.e. If you didn't pay for an extended range battery they enabled that DoD anyway.

Comment: Do these chargers use the neutral wire? If not, why is the NEMA 14-50R  being used rather than a receptacle without the neutral?

Comment: Good idea to do it right - there's a risk that someone will pull up with a suitable extension cord or a very long charge cord and suddenly there are two cars charging at once.

Comment: If I understand the Tesla charger's capability, it can be manually switched to limit the charging current to say 24 A even if the vehicle could accept a higher current. Is that correct? And if the other charger plugged into the NEMA 14-50 could also be limited similarly, then two vehicles could be charged at the same time and not trip the breaker (60 A?) feeding the sub-panel set-up proposed by @Harper. So this would allow two electric vehicles to be charged simultaneously at a pretty high power even if it was below the max the vehicles could take.

Comment: @JimStewart Right.  Though if you followed my advice, any of the Siemens 8-space panels are 125A rated, so the only difference between that panel fed by a 60A main vs a 100 or 125A main is the wire and the breaker in the main panel.

Comment: @JimStewart You can set the amperage on the Tesla charger, but that requires dissembling the unit (exposing hot wires, meaning you'll want to switch off the breaker). So in any practical sense you would set it once and leave it, which largely defeats the purpose of installing a Level 2 charger.

Comment: Oh, I had gotten the idea that it was conveniently manually controlled to limit the current to a user selected value. So this is not the case. But a level 2 charger does charge at a higher rate than a level 1, right, so a level 2 would allow 200 miles of range to be added overnight or 100 miles in a few hours. You can't do this with a level 1, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it with a switch, you would need a DPDT switch with one throw wired to the charger, the other wired to the receptacle.   The DPDT switch would need to be rated for the ampacity of the circuit, which means it's going to be BIG.  For example, this GE switch would work:

[image: GE TC35322]

It might be easier to just install the receptacle, and cord and plug connect the charger.

Answer (score 9):

You are not allowed to put multiple outlets on a 50A/60A circuit.   You can on a 30A, and that would've been simple, but that will slow charge.

However, your Tesla charger wants 60A and **you cannot put a 50A receptacle on a 60A circuit**.

[image]

Really, the best way to do this is a **subpanel**.  ***But wait.***

The keystone is a $30 interlock kit made by Siemens for its panels.  **This replaces the expensive, huge  Frankenstein switch**. The interlock kit straps between two 2-pole breakers, making it so only one can be on at a time.  This is intended for generator interlocks, where the breakers are back-fed, but it's fine to normal-feed the breakers too.  So your cost is

- $30 [interlock kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Q01XSS)
- $40 8-space, main-lug (no breaker on the sub**) panel
- $18 two 40-60A breakers, $9 each
- $5 ground bar

I also got you 4 extra spaces in the panel to use as you please.

You feed the lugs normally, you don't backfeed. The two breakers on the interlock are

- a 60A breaker going to the Hardwired Tesla charger, full rate unthrottled
- a **50A** breaker going to the NEMA 14-50, *which is the legal/right way to do that*

And honestly, I do not see a reason you can't simply forego the interlock and allow both outlets to be hot at the same time.  The breaker in the main panel protects the wiring to the subpanel and the subpanel itself (which is rated 125A), and the individual breakers protect the wiring to the equipment.  If you try to charge two cars at once without rate throttling, yeah, you'll trip the breaker downstairs.

The feed from the main panel to this subpanel can be any size of wire you please, as long as the breaker in the main panel protects the wire.  At these sizes, there are no brownie points for using copper*, so consider aluminum wire/cable.  For 60A feeder, use #6Cu or #4Al.  For 100A feeder, #3Cu or #1Al at which point you *definitely* don't need the interlock. (You're allowed to oversubscribe a panel and this won't matter).

* Aluminum feeder does not have the problem that 1970s branch circuits had.  The metal conducts 12x better per dollar. This is why it is widely used on feeder, where the mineral value becomes a significant part of cable cost.

** because it's not needed in subpanels in the same building, a breaker *is* needed in the main panel to feed/protect the cable run. Getting the subpanel main to pop before the feed breaker doesn't work, without deep-diving into SCADA tech.

Comment: Just curious, not familiar with US electrical code: Would wiring an extra 50A breaker in series with the 50A socket on the 60A circuit make it OK?

Comment: @rackandboneman That's what a subpanel **is**.   Keep in mind the US does not have discrete breakers where you can stick a bit of DIN rail inside any enclosure and slap a breaker there.  Our breakers are cheap ($5) but can only possibly fit in "expensive" breaker panels ($20 and up).  Since the cost is not prohibitive, you are expected to do things that way.  The Tesla and subpanel could not share a 60A branch because *60A branches can't be shared at all*, and also anything feeding a panel is feeder by definition. You can't hang individual loads on feeder.

Comment: You guessed right that I am from a DIN rail region :) I would have assumed such breakers to be available anywhere in the world, albeit more for industrial switching cabinets and stuff...

Comment: @rackandboneman they are [available](https://www.amazon.com/American-Electrical-C50A2P-2-Poles-Mounted/dp/B00TIKC9IY).  They just aren't competitive given how stupid-cheap our normal panels are... and also, not UL approved for individual use outside a compatible service panel, which smokes any possible cost advantage.

Comment: Subpanel, +1. Forget all that non-sense: hemmed in by design, both receptacles *cannot* be used at the same time, so there's no need for a disconnect.

Comment: I'd imagine not wanting to risk tripping the house breaker by trying to charge 2 cars at once would be the motivation for wanting an interlock to only power on charger at a time.  That goal should still be possible without an interlock though, just use a smaller sub-panel so that the subpanel's main breaker trips if both chargers go live simultaneously.

Comment: @DanNeely doesn't work, because you still need to protect the wire *to* the subpanel with a ~60A breaker in the main panel.  It is impossible to "sequence" breakers, i.e. Get the more convenient one to trip first.  In an outbuilding for instance, Murphy's Law requires the breaker in the other building to trip anytime it is raining.

Comment: @Harper -- my understanding is that North American (UL489) DIN rail breakers can be mounted to DIN rail in a suitable NEMA enclosure (not necessarily a made-for-purpose panelboard cabinet), but that enclosure then must comply with NEC 312.6 bending space rules, which makes many otherwise-suitable enclosures (such as the Altech EK series) hard to apply.

Comment: @DanNeely -- selective coordination of circuit breakers is a tricky business at best that is generally unsupported for light-duty panelboard breakers.

Comment: Since EV owners are likely to have guests with EVs and some EV chargers use a NEMA 6-50 whereas others evidently use a NEMA 14-50, the subpanel approach of @Harper would allow having a TESLA charger hardwired for the resident and would allow installation of both a NEMA 6-50R and a NEMA 14-50R to accommodate any EV charger. Although I gather there are adaptors to allow a NEMA 6-50P to connect to a NEMA 14-50R so all that is needed is a 14-50R.